# Replace multiple words in single column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to replace some words with others in the same column using VBA.
Currently, I'm able to replace single word but I want to replace multiple words at the same time.

Below is code-

```
Sub replce()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Replace _
 What:="Ryan Group", Replacement:="COS", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

But, I want to replace like

```
Sub replce()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Replace _
What:= "Ryan Group, Zyan Group, Wayn Group", Replacement:="COS, TAN, SIN"
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

How can I replace the multiple words? can I implement this by using any other VBA code?
Please help. Thanks in advance.
Be safe!

Comment: replace them one by one

Comment: Use two arrays, one with the original words, and one with the replacement words, and a loop.

Comment: @BigBen yeah, I thought of using the loop. But I'm new in this so, I'm don't really know how to use the loop.

Comment: I found too many VB codes but none of them is working for me, this one is simple and working without any error but I just want to use the loop in it. I dont know how to use array and loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two arrays and a loop:

```
Sub replce()
    Dim fromList() As Variant
    Dim toList() As Variant
    
    fromList = Array("Ryan Group", "Zyan Group", "Wayn Group")
    toList = Array("COS", "TAN", "SIN")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(fromList) To UBound(fromList)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Replace _
            What:=fromList(i), Replacement:=toList(i), _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you could try the below code:

```
Sub replce()

    Dim strWhat As String, strRep As String
    Dim arrWhat As Variant, arrRep As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    strWhat = "Ryan Group, Zyan Group, Wayn Group"
    strRep = "COS, TAN, SIN"
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C")
    
        arrWhat = Split(strWhat, ",")
        arrRep = Split(strRep, ",")
        
        For i = LBound(arrWhat) To UBound(arrWhat)
            .Replace What:=Trim(arrWhat(i)), Replacement:=Trim(arrRep(i)), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        Next i
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```